# How to specify location on Bing in the URL

Tags: php, curl, bing

I am doing some minor cURL work and, unlike Google, Bing defaults the search results to the location of the server. I am trying to find a parameter to set that allows me to specify location, for example UK/US, but I haven't had much luck.

Does anyone know or have a link to an article explaining this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4):

I actually found it, after searching for 30 minutes and posting this I stumbled upon it. You can set it using the something like "setmkt=fr-fr"

Where the first is the language, the second the location. I can't be sure what it will accept but I figure playing with that will get the desired results.

Comment: `setmkt` seems to be equivalent to `mkt`. Accepted values are documented at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd251064.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Bing! probably does it based on the IP of the connecting client.

Since you can't change that (other than connecting via a proxy, which is a whole different story), you cannot manually set the location for your search results (unless of course, Bing! has an option or an API which allows it).

Answer (score 0):

I believe you could use the `Location Data` parameter:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff701726.aspx

You can specify `countryRegion` to limit the results to a certain country:

> A string specifying the country or region name of an address.
>
> Example: United States